# Wedge product of a $k$-form and a $1$-form

Tags: differential-geometry

The wedge product of a $k$-form $\alpha \in \Omega^k(M)$ and a $1$-form $\beta \in \Omega^1(M)$ is given by

$$
\alpha \wedge \beta(X_0,\dots,X_k) = \sum \text{sgn}(\sigma)\alpha(X_{\sigma(0)},\dots,X_{\sigma(k-1)})\beta(X_{\sigma(k)})
$$

where $X_i$'s are vector fields and  $\sigma$ runs over all $(k+1)$-shuffles. Can someone explain why the formula reduces to

$$
\alpha \wedge \beta(X_0,\dots,X_k) = \sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\alpha(X_0,\dots,\widehat{X_i},\dots,X_k)\beta(X_i)?
$$

I don't see how these are equivalent.

Comment: use that $\alpha$ is alternating.

Comment: Are you sure that these do not differ by a constant factor (like $k!$)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Isn't that the case when we sum over permutations instead of shuffles?

Comment: Writing out the initial sum for a small value of $k$ (say $2$ or $3$) will help you understand the relationship between the two formulae and whether you are missing a constant factor as Ted Shifrin suggests.